# Does Boolean.parseBoolean() evaluate a constant expression every time inside a loop, or is there any optimization taking place?

Tags: java, boolean, compiler-optimization, properties-file

I have some legacy java code in a data capturing program meant to read data byte-by-byte from a serial port.

```
private void processByte(byte b) {
    
    if(Boolean.parseBoolean(prop.getProperty("PRINT_RECEIVED_BYTES"))) {
        System.out.println("Current byte received: ASCII Decimal value: " + b + ", Char value: " + (char) b);
    }
.
.
.
}
```

My concern is: Is the parsing of the property PRINT_RECEIVED_BYTES (which can be either `true` or `false`) evaluated for every run of the `processByte()` method?
Should I bother to change the code and store the parsed property value in a boolean field, to be used in the `if` statement inside `processByte()`?

The properties are read from a file only once when the program starts. The method is being called from inside a loop for every byte of data received.

Comment: Java tends to do just what you told it to do. If you didn't tell it to save the result in a variable, it gets re-evaluated.

Comment: If the property can never change during execution, then I would recommend caching it.

Comment: `prop.getProperty("PRINT_RECEIVED_BYTES")` is definitely not a constant expression.